# How do I create some kind of if statement on ms access if I am doing a booking system

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

OK, so I am doing a course booking system via webpage which connects to a server and a database on ms access. In this database I have the tables *tblcustomer* -which contains all customer information- and *tblcourse* -which has all the details of all abailable courses. To book an individual course has a courseid and client has clientid, i have set up a tblcustcourse combining the 2. however I am unsure of how to create some sort of function to stop more entries being added to an individual course being booked on when the maxentrants criteria is filled,

The basic plan is that on the site the client will try to book on to said course and then the server will check the databes as to wether there is availability on the course or if it is full (depends on maxentrants). So how do I link all this work ?

Comment: havent got one yet for access. no idea if what i want is even possible- or do you want my html?

Comment: @diEcho my html isnt linked to this yet- need to figure out how to do the access thing first

Comment: @TobiasWhite Would you mind to review your post? Take an eye of spelling and punctation. Your text is hardly to understand. Maybe using short and simply sentences would be helpful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, one would use Classic ASP/VBScript or .NET as middleware to accept the web requests and execute them against your MS Access database. You can use DB objects, where you can represent a recordset in code, or simple execute direct SQL statements against the DB (which you should sterilize to prevent SQJ injection attacks).

If you're not a core programmer, Classic ASP is probably the easier route since you can build your code in a text editor and do not need to compile. There are many, many articles on using Classic ASP to talk to MS Access in a web environment.

See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages

http://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/connecting-to-an-access-database.htm